# Stuck with normal map baking, normal map is showing both low and high poly?

Tags: baking, normal-map

I'll link the images below, but basically, when I baked my high poly to low poly, it seems to have worked somewhat but it baked both of them some how? I'm new to blender and have been using lots of tutorials for normal map baking but all them go wrong or just don't work right? I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong exactly but hopefully someone on here can help, been stuck on this step of making a character model for several months. I can also send/upload my blend file if need be but I don't know how to in this question.

[screenshots of my issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c38K5.jpg)

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIFs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure both of your meshes are set to *Smooth Shaded* (select the object and right-click) and turn off the Auto Smooth setting.

[[image: turn off the Auto Smooth option].

Comment: Thanks so much, didn't think small options/checks were the problem.